# Windows 10 Developer Mode

Tags: windows-10, windows-store

I have Windows 10 Pro (upgraded from Windows 8.1 Pro WMC) and I see that the option "Don't use developer features" is greyed out/disabled/cannot be selected and the option "Sideload apps" is selected. Why can't I select "Don't use developer features"? How can I enable it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is mainly due to group policy feature being enforced. You can go to group policy to enable it manually.

Search for Group Policy Editor and navigate to
Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > App Package Deployment

Enable

1. Allow all trusted apps to install
2. Allows development of Windows Store apps and installing them from an integrated development environment (IDE).

[image]

Comment: When I did those changes, everything greyed out and the developer mode was preselected, but when I reverted them back to no setting, it finally presented to me all the options. Thanks a lot!!!