# Windows Developer not enabled

Tags: windows, development-environment

I'm trying to activate developper option 
[developpement option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jkaB.png)

http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/389038Sanstitre.png

please i try all things but this option still not activated, what should i do thanks first

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to modify these keys in the registry?

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModelUnlock\AllowAllTrustedApps
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModelUnlock\AllowDevelopmentWithoutDevLicense
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i have not this keys :/ look:

http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/565205Sanstitre.png

Comment: Are you sure you enabled the `Allow all trusted apps to install` and 
`Allows development of Windows Store apps and installing them from an integrated development environment (IDE)` in the GroupPolicy?

Comment: You can also add those 2 registry key into the right location.

Comment: yes sir, am sure that all the 4 options are enables, look:
http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/381959Sanstitre.png

Comment: i add the 2 keys i restart my pc but still not enable :(
look: http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/199455Sanstitre.png

Comment: I'm not good with French, but it looks enabled for me. It says Developer mode, isn't it? Can you run a PowerShell in administrator mode and run this code to verify : `show-windowsdeveloperlicenseregistration`

Comment: he's give me this window :
http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=248650zh120301.png

Comment: Have a look on this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33333457/windows-10-developer-mode) Go to GPedit and set it back them to `no setting`.

Comment: Mmm my windows 10 is not activated thats why --', i want show my desktop icon and the system say that windows is not activated... windows 10 is free why he's not activated o..O

Comment: Its not free. :) The upgrade from an activated system is free.